# Reasons not to use these leads

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, multimeter, voltage-measurement

I found the following note with a set of test leads we use for our Agilent 34461A<sup>[[1]](https://www.atecorp.com/products/keysight-technologies/34461a)[[2]](http://www.tequipment.net/Agilent/34461A/)</sup>:

> This Test Lead Set is designed for use with the Agilent 34xxxA Multimeters, and also the U274A, U3401A, and U3402A Multimeters. Do not use with the Agilent 3458A.

I suppose they're simply not calibrated for use with other meters and 'too inferior' for use with the 3458A<sup>[[3]](https://www.atecorp.com/products/keysight-technologies/3458a)</sup>.

Aside from precision, is there any reason not to use them on a different multimeter, provided they fit?

Comment: Please add links so everyone who don't know exactly what the 34461A model is doesn't have to do the job..

Comment: @pipe Sure, on it.

Comment: @pipe Links to the original Agilent documentation appear to be down, so third-party links will have to do.

Comment: In general, it is very poor documentation practice to say "Don't" without saying exactly "Why Not". You should not have had to ask here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In addition to the excellent answer given by @JorenVaes there is also a simpler electro mechanical reason for this caution. If you take a close look at the lead connections for the 34xxxA multimeters you can see that they are made like shown here:

[image]

The above type of jacks are designed to be used with the shrouded type of banana plugs that look like these:

[image]

[image]

On the other hand the 3458A meter uses test lead connections that look like this:

[image]

As you can see the shrouded leads will not mate with the latter type of jacks. Shrouded banana plugs have come into use on many meters because of the safety they offer. The types of meters may be used in high voltage or high current applications where the user may detach the lead from the meter when it is still clipped into the test circuit.

Comment: Of course! I didn't even think of that. I'm so used to using unshrouded leads in my day-to-day life, I forgot that it's impossible to plug the shrouded safety leads into anything that's not built for them.

Answer (score 15):

The 3458A is an 8 1/2 digit, calibration/metrology grade instrument. When measuring 1V, your least significant digits will be nanovolts. At this level of accuracy, you need to pay attention to triboelectric effects, thermal EMF and so on. This requires another class of test leads, usually using tellurium-copper alloys (for the EMF,) teflon insulation, shielding when doing current/resistance measurements, etc. Such things are not found in your run-of-the-mill test leads because it's too expensive and such.

Of course, if you are just doing quick and dirty measurements, you don't really need to care too much - you won't break your 8 1/2 digit meter by using normal probes.